# Internal file picker in Android 4.4 Kitkat

Tags: android, permissions, android-4.4-kitkat

My app (Keepass2Android) has an internal file picker for locating password databases, key files etc. (It was mainly integrated to browse cloud providers like Dropbox, SkyDrive, ...).

I have therefore added a permission

```
<permission android:description="@string/permission_desc" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="KP2A internal file browsing" android:name="keepass2android.keepass2android.permission.KP2aInternalFileBrowsing" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

with `android:protectionLevel="signature"`.

The file picker activity is marked with `android:permission="keepass2android.keepass2android.permission.KP2aInternalFileBrowsing"` so that my internal file picker doesn't show up if other apps use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. (This wouldn't be really bad but it's not a very advanced file picker and certainly not the main purpose of my app to provide files, so I think it would be rather surprising for users to see my app come up).

This works great until Android 4.3, but with Android 4.4 it doesn't: My app still shows on the left side of the Storage Access Framework's file picker. But if a users click it, this leads to a `SecurityException: Permission denied.`

```
    12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* cmp=keepass2android.keepass2android/group.pals.android.lib.ui.filechooser.FileChooserActivity } from ProcessRecord{42623050 16058:com.android.documentsui/u0a81} (pid=16058, uid=10081) requires keepass2android.keepass2android.permission.KP2aInternalFileBrowsing
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2096)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity.onAppPicked(DocumentsActivity.java:926)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at com.android.documentsui.RootsFragment$2.onItemClick(RootsFragment.java:183)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-16 06:13:33.393 E/AndroidRuntime(16058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-16 06:13:33.393 W/ActivityManager(  580):   Force finishing activity com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity
12-16 06:13:33.904 W/ActivityManager(  580): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{42f84718 u0 com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity t42 f}
```

I guess this is happening because the Storage Access Framework's UI runs in another process which doesn't have my permission.

Is there any way to keep the intended behavior or should I simply remove the permission so this works with all Android versions?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an internal-only activity, just drop the intent filter.

In theory the proper way to avoid external apps from knowing about your components would be setting their exported property to false from their declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

However, as commonsware already explain [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/30/if-your-activity-has-intent-filter-export-it.html), there is unfortunately a bug in the stock Android chooser which will ignore the "exported" status of activities when listing them, and then crash if they are clicked by the user (a similar error to what you are experimenting).

So the best thing you can do, as far as I know, is just to eliminate your intent filter tag from your activity declaration, and call it with an explicit intent instead.